# db.serverStatus() got not authorized on admin to execute command

Tags: mongodb

My mongo version : 2.6.11
I want to  check `db.serverStatus()` in my `robomomgo`
But got errmsg:

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { serverStatus:   1.0 }",
    "code" : 13
}
```

How can I add authorization  ??

I find a command can create user with authorization :

```
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "tester",
      pwd: "password",
      roles: [             
         { role: "readWrite", db: "test" }
      ]
    }
);
```

But I don't know which is `db.serverStatus()` 's database name??
How can I authorize it??

Answer (score 16):

You need to grant the `clusterMonitor` role to the user running  the `db.serverStatus` command. You can grant this role to a user by calling the `grantRolestoUser.

[Here's a list](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#clusterMonitor) of other clusterMonitor roles

```
use admin

db.createUser(
    {
      user: "clustermonitor",
      pwd: "password",
      roles: [             
         { role: "readWrite", db: "admin" }
      ]
    }
);

db.grantRolesToUser(
  "clusterMonitor",
   [
     { role: "clusterMonitor", db:"admin"} 
   ]
);
```

Comment: Two notes: This can be done in one command by adding the `clusterMonitor` role to the roles array in the `createUser` statement. And, of course, one has to authenticate against the `admin` database.

Comment: Opps, the createUser and grantRolesToUser work on two distinct users, i.e. "clustermonitor" != "clusterMonitor.